# Canceling a User Interview

Tags: user-research, research

I made a recruitment error by scheduling an interview with a participant who isn't fit for my study. What is the appropriate protocol for canceling an interview?

Comment: A phone call, maybe?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about scheduling rather than UX.

Comment: I think this is a question about recruiting for user studies, not job recruiting. It's a good topic for this site.

Comment: How is it off-topic? It is definitely about UX!

Comment: This looks like it might be a better fit for Academia because it's about the ethics and protocol of conducting a study involving human volunteers.

Comment: It's a user interview for a study involving a user interface. It IS a UX issue and other practitioners can benefit from the question/answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can reach the person prior to 24 hours before the study, then just contact them to cancel. No big deal.

If not, you might think about paying them some portion of the compensation they would have received.

And, of course, thank them and keep them in mind for future studies (if they might fit into another one).